# Trying to get an asterisk * as input to main from command line

Tags: c, windows, command-line, mingw

I'm trying to send input from the command line to my main function. The input is then sent to the functions checkNum etc.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int x = checkNum(argv[1]);
    int y = checkNum(argv[3]);
    int o = checkOP(argv[2]);
    …
}
```

It is supposed to be a calculator so for example in the command line when I write:

```
program.exe 4 + 2
```

and it will give me the answer 6 (code for this is not included).

The problem is when I want to multiply and I type for example

```
program.exe 3 * 4
```

It seems like it creates a pointer (or something, not quite sure) instead of giving me the char pointer to the char '`*`'.

The question is can I get the input '`*`' to behave the same way as when I type '+'?

Edit: Writing `"*"` in the command line works. Is there a way where I only need to type `*`?

The code is running on Windows, which seems to be part of the problem.

Comment: try `3 "*" 4`, if that works then it's not your problem, but the problem of your terminal / commandline. in that case consider entering the whole expression as one string in quotes...

Comment: You may have to quote it.  E.g.: `program.exe 3 "*" 4`.  Certainly you would need to do on Unix (including Linux and OS X), because the `*` has special pattern-matching significance to the shell.  Your program name suggests you are running on Windows, and there it *used* to be the case that programs were responsible for doing their own globbing.  Perhaps that has changed.

Comment: Thenks for your reply! I tried that and it does work, so now the question is if it is possible to do without writing " ". Will edit post

Comment: can you share the code for the helper functions?

Comment: @Frostbite What shell you are on? Is it unix-like shell (such as mingw) or windows powershell?

Comment: Alternatively, you could receive the entire expression as a single argument by quoting the whole string: `program.exe "3 * 4"` but then you'd need to tokenize the string yourself.

Comment: Try `\*` instead of `*` in the command line. If this works, then this is not a `C`  question but a `bash` question. More important: you won't get a `C` answer in that case.

Comment: "Blue Moon I am using mingw for windows and im using it whit the comand line ( cmd) on windows 7

Comment: Does using `\*` instead of `'*'` or `"*"` count?  Didn't think so.

Comment: This is not a C problem. The `*` has a special meaning on the Windows command line, simple as that.

Comment: @Lundin my Windows 7 console command line exhibits none of these problems. The argument `*` to a C program is printed as a `*` and `echo *` works exactly like `echo 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off the shell globbing if you don't want to use single quote (`'`) or double quote (`"`).

Do

```
# set -o noglob
```

or

```
# set -f
```

(both are equivalent).

to turn off the shell globbing. Now, the shell won't expand any globs, including `*`.

Comment: @RaviRaj This should work on bash/mingw. The question was about mingw on Windows. Are you using mingw/bash or some other shell (like Powershell)?

Comment: I'm using normal Windows command prompt. It is showing that `Environment variable -o noglob not defined` and `Environment variable -f not defined`.

Comment: @RaviRaj That's not bash/mingw shell. You can instead try with single quotes to prevent glob expansion in Windows cmd prompt and Powershell.

Comment: But when I write `'*'` it is passed as it is, with single quotes included. How to pass only a `*` character?

Answer (score 7):

As @JohnBollinger wrote in the comments, you should use

```
/path/to/program 3 '*' 4
```

the way it's written at the moment.

But some explanation is clearly required. This is because the shell will parse the command line before passing it to your program. `*` will expand to any file in the directory (UNIX) or something similar (windows), space separated. This is not what you need. You cannot fix it within your program as it will be too late. (On UNIX you can ensure you are in an empty directory but that probably doesn't help).

Another way around this is to quote the entire argument (and rewrite you program appropriately), i.e.

```
/path/to/program '3 * 4'
```

in which case you would need to use `strtok_r` or `strsep` to step through the (single) argument passed, separating it on the space(s).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explination and your time! I appreciate it

Answer (score 6):

How the shell handles the command-line arguments is outside the scope and control of your program.  There is nothing you can put in the program to tell the shell to avoid performing any of its normal command-handling behavior.

I suggest, however, that instead of relying on the shell for word splitting, you make your program expect the whole expression as a single argument, and for it to parse the expression.  That will not relieve you of the need for quotes, but it will make the resulting commands look more natural:

```
program.exe 3+4
program.exe "3 + 4"
program.exe "4*5"
```

That will also help if you expand your program to handle more complex expressions, such as those containing parentheses (which are also significant to the shell).

Comment: Thanks, thought it might be somwhere along that line, and it makes sense!