# My C program unable to detect multiplication symbol

Tags: c

I have a simple command prompt program(For example, "a 1 + 2" prints 3) that works perfectly except no matter what I try, the multiplication symbol (*) seems unable to go from command line to program correctly.

the functions are cast as such

```
void math(int argc, char **argv) {
int result;
int first = atoi(argv[1]);
int second = atoi(argv[3]);

if(*argv[2] == '+') {
    addition(first,second);
}

else if(*argv[2] == '-') {
    subtraction(first,second);
}

else if(*argv[2] == '*') {
    multiplication(first,second);
}
else{
    printf("Syntax error \n");
}
```

and performs as such

```
addition (int first, int second){
printf("%d",first + second);
```

}

```
subtraction (int first, int second) {
printf("%d",first - second);
```

}

```
multiplication (int first, int second) {
    printf("%d",first * second);
}
```

Through testing for example switching the '+' sign in the addition function to '*' just to check if I did some clumsy mistake, but it appears to not be the case. Attempting user input with the * symbol causes the program to skip down to my "syntax error" else clause.

Comment: The `*` character is a special wildcard character. Perhaps try escaping it with a backslash or putting it in quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get an asterisk \* as input to main from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069400/trying-to-get-an-asterisk-as-input-to-main-from-command-line)

Comment: My Windows 7 console command line exhibits none of these problems, nor those mentioned in the linked question. The argument `*` for a C program is printed as a `*` and `echo *` works exactly like `echo 1`.

Comment: I think your `*` is running into a shell expansion issue. Can you show how you're using it from the terminal?

Comment: That's a good point Jorgel. I searched "multiplication symbol" and "*", but I suppose i missed searching for "asterisk".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shell (or command prompt) has performed [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), escape the `*` when you execute your program (with quotes or `\`).

Answer (score 2):

Because the command shell is interpreting the "*".  You will need to put it in quotes to pass it to your program, like:

```
 > math 2 "*" 3
```

Comment: Is there are reason why this works with + - / % and not *?
edit: nevermind, I misunderstood you

Comment: @Flowdorio `*` is a wildcard character in the shell. It's the same thing that happens when you type `ls *.c` or such.

Comment: @Flowdorio Yes. The reason can be seen when you run `echo *` vs `echo /`.